# Three.js Simulate Floor Reflection

Tags: reflection, three.js

### **Objective** :

I want to simulate a reflective floor ([like this](http://www.lastonepoets.com/gallery/thumbs/lrg-89-cook_crema_marfil_marble_floorrestoration_008.jpg)) in three.js

Also, I **don't** want to duplicate the house and make a transparent floor as that increases the size of the model.

I tried setting up a cubeCamera and rendered its output to floor but it always shows black.

```
        mirrorCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.01, 1000, 512);
        mirrorCamera.renderTarget.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
        scene.add(mirrorCamera);

        var mirrorFloorMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
                    {
                        map: floorTexture,
                        reflectivity: .8,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                        envMap: mirrorCamera.renderTarget
                    });

        mirrorFloor = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeom, mirrorFloorMaterial);

        mirrorFloor.doubleSided = true;
        mirrorCamera.position = mirrorFloor.position;

        scene.add(mirrorFloor);
        ......
        ......
        //in render()

        mirrorFloor.visible = false;
        mirrorCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
        mirrorFloor.visible = true;

        renderer.render(scene, firstPerson.camera);
```

### **Questions**:

1) Why do I always see black in place of floor and not what cubeCamera should have rendered?

2) Can anyone suggest a neat way to simulate floor reflections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Meshes can share geometry, so rendering the reflection as a separate mesh doesn't imply duplicating the geometry. See this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text

Comment: Yes. But I **don't** want to add separate meshes to simulate reflection (even if it means reusing previous geometry) as that would mean higher load.

Ideally, I would like to check how it looks from a **mirrorCamera** (which is placed at negative y axis as that of FirstPerson Camera) and overlay that over the texture of the floor. 

Is it possible to do that? 

Also, are there any problems with this method for simulating reflection?